# how to cheack first character of text input is X if length is 6 using Jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

I wanted to validate a HTML text box using Jquery...in that text box i wanted to accept only numbers, if the length is 6-it must contain only numiricals and if legth is 7 it must conain alphabet X at the beginning.

```
<input type="text" class="stid" id="stn" name="stn"  maxlength="7" placeholder="Number should be 7 digits followed by letter X" required>
```

I tried the application using java script its working fine but how to implement using JQuery.
my javascript code

```
var textBox = document.getElementById("stn");
    var textLength = textBox.value.length;
    if((textLength < 7 || textLength > 7))
    {
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML="Student Number should be 7 digits if it not follwed by x";
    return false;
    }
    else{
    if((textLength < 6 ))
    {
    //<!--to check the first letter is x in student number-->
    var firstChar = document.getElementById("stn").value.charAt(0);
    if( firstChar !== "x" && firstChar !== "X")
    {
                                                                                            document.getElementById("name").innerHTML="error message,";
        return false;
    }
    }
    }
```

How to implement this with Jquery?

Comment: If it works in JavaScript, why are you trying to shove the jQuery framework on top of it?  Realize that jQuery **is** javascript.  In this case, the only thing you could do easier is use selectors to get your elements, and it's less convenient.

Comment: IF it work with Javascript, why would you want to di it with jQuery?

Comment: The problem with the logic is that the second conditonal will never be true

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
var length = $('#stn').val().length;
if( length != 7 ){
    $('#name').html('Student Number should be 7 digits if it not follwed by x');
}else if(length < 6){
    var firstChar = $('#stn').val().value.charAt(0);
    if(firstChar != 'x' && firstChar != 'X'){
         $('#name').html('error message');
    }
}
```

But like this the second conditional will never be true, I think you want this:

```
    var length = $('#stn').val().length;
    if(length < 6){
        var firstChar = $('#stn').val().value.charAt(0);
        if(firstChar != 'x' && firstChar != 'X'){
             $('#name').html('error message');
        }
    }else if( length != 7 ){
        $('#name').html('Student Number should be 7 digits if it not follwed by x');
    }
```

Comment: The problem with the logic is that the second conditonal will never enter

Comment: You'll want to tweak `var firstChar = $('#stn').val().value`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, would you elaborate a little bit the reason?

Comment: It should just be `$('#stn').val().charAt(0)`, right?  `val()` will return a string, `.value` was just an artifact from the OP?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to post code to make a point.  Toni's answer is everything you need, and is much more efficiently coded.  I'm posting mine because it *doesn't* translate your logic and make it more concise, in an attempt to draw a distinction between "porting to jQuery" and "coding well."  Toni's answer does both.  Mine will show your exact logic, using jQuery:

```
var textBox = $("#stn");
var textLength = textBox.val().length;
if((textLength < 7 || textLength > 7))
{
    $("#name").html("Student Number should be 7 digits if it not follwed by x");
    return false;
} 
else
{
    if((textLength < 6 ))
    {
        //<!--to check the first letter is x in student number-->
        var firstChar = $("#stn").val().charAt(0);
        if( firstChar !== "x" && firstChar !== "X")
        {
            $("#name").html("error message,");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Even in my case, I neatened up your code by fixing spacing.  My point is that jQuery doesn't necessarily do much for you.

If you want to take advantage of *JavaScript*'s regex utility, you can shorten this considerably:

```
var val = document.getElementById("stn").value;
if (!val.match(/[xX]?[0-9]{6}/)) {
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "Student number should be 6 digits with an optional x or X in front";
    return false;
}
```

Rewriting this in jQuery shows very little difference:

```
var val = $("#stn").val();
if (!val.match(/[xX]?[0-9]{6}/)) {
    $("#name").html("Student number should be 6 digits with an optional x or X in front");
    return false;
}

}
```